# How to select all text in cmd output if there is too much text?

Tags: cmd.exe

I run an application via `cmd`; after it is done I want to select all text from the start, but `cmd` will not let me do that.

I already tried with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> and choice `select all`, and `copy`; however `cmd` just let me select all final text. The text is too big, and I can't scroll up fully.

How would I capture all output?

Comment: Try using `[command] | clip` or `[command] >> [outputfilename].txt` to select entire text generated from command to clipboard or a text file.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto this sounds like a perfect answer to me. Post it as an answer and you'll get an upvote from me. :)

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto - This stops data being written to the screen, but the questioner wants to know how to capture what has already been written. To do this, type `Ctrl-m` to mark text, `Ctrl-a` to select all, and `Enter` to copy the selected text to the clip-board. Alternatively, if you select `QuickEdit Mode` in **Properties** -> **Options**, you can select with left-click and drag, and copy with right-click.

Answer (score 3):

You can use either piping to `clip` (copy to clipboard) or using stream to provide command output to a text file:

```
[command] | clip

[command] >> [outputfilename].txt
```

The first command copies entire command output to the clipboard which can be captured in Notepad or any other word-processors, and the second command generates stream which directly append to end of a text file if the file exists, or create a new file if the file name doesn't exist before then fill it with command output.

**Update:** If you want to display output in both CMD screen and outputting to text file simultaneously, use this way:

```
[command] >> [outputfilename].txt & type [outputfilename].txt
```

The `type` command reads all contents of the output file immediately after the command finished and display them as part of command line text.

NB: [command] is any recognizable command syntax you want to run with.

Further reference:

[CMD: Export all the screen content to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042476/cmd-export-all-the-screen-content-to-a-text-file)

Comment: +1 from me as promised. Thanks for posting the answer. :)

Comment: C:\Users\kotowari>Command | clip
'Command' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\kotowari>

Answer (score 0):

In a cmd.exe window you can right click, and select Mark.

Then with your mouse, you drag the selection on all the text you want copied, even the one outside the screen, while you are dragging, it will scroll up or down until you release the mouse button.

Once all the selection is done, you just press Enter, and all the selection will go straight to the Clipboard.

Comment: i use window 10. don't need mark. my text file in cmd too big .i can't use mouse select copy method. have any way to copy text file? i sill wait my answer.